# How to connect your CSV file to Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, export-to-csv, filenotfoundexception, jupyter-console

So I have a CSV file from google analytics called 'data-export' and I'm trying to use Python in Jupyter Notebook to basically open the file and then later, create charts for furhter analysis.

```
import pandas as pd
getCSV = pd.read_csv('data-export',skiprows=10,skipfooter=500,engine = 'python')
getCSV.head()

#error message
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data-export'
```

I tried using syntax I found online, however the error message keeps telling me filenotfound and no such file or directory. Can someone please explain exactly how I can get the code to read the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give it the full path to the file on your local machine, not just the name of it. Most file paths look like this: `C:\Users\yeetMan\Downloads\code\scratch.csv`

Go to the file in file explorer, click on it, and click "copy path". This will copy the full file path.

Make sure to include the .csv at the end.